# Use Wordpress as CMS and access content via REST API

Tags: wordpress, rest, content-management-system, wordpress-rest-api, contentful

I have used Contentful before to host content and access it in my application via REST. It works great however it is not free.

I am trying to find out if I can host my app's content similarly on Wordpress and access it in my app using its REST apis.

Does anybody know if we can and how? It is not that straight forward to figure out on their website.

PS: I don't care about the security about the website content.

Comment: The WordPress REST API provides RESTful access to the WordPress MySQL tables. To use this API without any coding you must convert your CMS to a WordPress CMS. If your existing CMS is structurally very different from the WordPress CMS this may be quite difficult.

Comment: There is a REST engine inside of WordPress and I suppose you could modify it to access your own tables. I do think this kind of work is not for beginners - at least I did not find it easy.

Comment: @magenta I do not have any CMS right now. This is a new feature I am trying to build in existing React application. Basically, I want to be able to change the content (which is just a "what's new" message) on landing page of my app. I can do that easily with contentful but want to see if there is cheaper/free alternative.

Comment: I don't think you need WordPress for something that simple. Just PHP can easily do that. PHP does not have REST builtin but it does have SQL access builtin and for something this basic it can be done directly in PHP.

Comment: However, WordPress can also do what you want and much, much more. I don't know what the future of your website will be but you may want to consider using WordPress even for something this simple even though it is a huge overkill as it provides for easy future enhancements.

Answer (score 0):

wordpress has an embeded REST API, this can be done easily, check the REST API Handbook in the following url  here: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/